# Disable use of port 5432 by postgres on startup

Tags: 18.04, startup, postgresql

I've removed postgres from Ubuntu 18.04 by running following command:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql postgresql-doc postgresql-common
```

After running above command, postgres was removed, but it still uses port 5432 automatically on startup and I could not connect to mentioned port (error: port already in use) from another service. The below command confirms use of port 5432:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
```

And result:

```
systemd-r   757 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  21495      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
epmd       1465        rabbitmq    3u  IPv4  27066      0t0  TCP *:4369 (LISTEN)
epmd       1465        rabbitmq    4u  IPv6  27067      0t0  TCP *:4369 (LISTEN)
postgres   1471        postgres    3u  IPv4  27110      0t0  TCP *:5432 (LISTEN)
postgres   1471        postgres    4u  IPv6  27117      0t0  TCP *:5432 (LISTEN)
beam.smp   1693        rabbitmq   44u  IPv4  29193      0t0  TCP *:25672 (LISTEN)
beam.smp   1693        rabbitmq   55u  IPv6  33853      0t0  TCP *:5672 (LISTEN)
teamviewe  1957            root   12u  IPv4  31003      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:5939 (LISTEN)
docker-pr  4030            root    4u  IPv6  39164      0t0  TCP *:6379 (LISTEN)
docker-pr  4060            root    4u  IPv6  40329      0t0  TCP *:5555 (LISTEN)
cupsd      5172            root    6u  IPv6  48402      0t0  TCP [::1]:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd      5172            root    7u  IPv4  48403      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:631 (LISTEN)
```

What can I do further to remove postgres completely or disable it on startup?

Comment: Check for any other postgr packages.  You might still have posgtresql-client-10 and postgresql-client-common

Comment: @ubfan1 Thanks for help! I uninstalled the packages you mentioned, but post '5432' was still used on startup. Then I removed user 'postgres' and only after that, my problem is solved.